# Visibility of variable inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

Is there a way to access the variable `i` inside the anonymous mouseover function?

```
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    results[i].addEventListener("mouseover", (function(event) {
      event.target.className = this.selectedClass;
      this.selectedIndex = i;
    }).bind(this), false);
    results[i].addEventListener("mouseout", (function(event) {
      event.target.className = '';
    }).bind(this), false);
  }
```

I did some research on closures, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: How isn't it working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: What you have "works". But it's likely not what you want. I assume you have the problem described by the duplicate question.